# Initial conditions to obtain a steady solution when an ordinary differential equation is given

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In a chemical reaction that follows the logistic equation, if the initial velocity is 0, it becomes a steady solution. However, in the equation of motion, the fact that the initial velocity is 0 does not necessarily mean that it is a steady solution.

For example,for the $$\frac{dx}{dt}(t) = 4(1-0.5x(t))x(t)$$,
under the initial condition (dx/dt)(0)=0　(that means initial velocity is 0), x(t) becomes a stationary solution, that means x(t)=const, here, x(t) means the solution of the above equation under the initial condition,  (dx/dt)(0)=0.

However, in the case of the equation of motion, even if the initial velocity is 0, it does not necessarily mean that it will not means the stationary solution.

**My questions**

> Am I right if
>
> - In the first-order differential equation, the initial velocity is 0
>   ⇒ The solution under the "initial velocity is 0 "is Steady solution, and
> - In the second-order differential equation, the initial velocity and initial acceleration are 0
>   ⇒ The solution under the "initial velocity and initial acceleration are 0 " is Steady solution ?
>
> If so, why,  If not, give a counterexample.

In other words, I would like you to determine the correctness or incorrectness of the following conjunction1 and 2, and provide corrections, proofs, counterexamples, etc.

**Conjunction1:**

> Let X:\mathbb{R}^n+1\to \mathbb{R} be a $C^\infty$ function
> Assume that the first-order ordinary differential equation
> $$\frac{dx}{dt} = X(t,x(t)) $$
> has a stationary solution.
> Also assume that c(t) is one of the solutions to this equation. At this time,
> $\ \ \exists t_0$ s,t $\frac{dc}{dt}(t_0)=0$
> ⇔$\forall t \in domain[c] ,\ \  c(t)=const$".

**Conjunction2:**

> Let $X:\mathbb{R}^2n+1\to \mathbb{R}$ be a $\mathbb{c}^infty$ function.
> The second-order ordinary differential equation
> $$\frac{d^2x}{d^2t} = X(t,\frac{dx}{dt} ,x(t))$$
> is assumed to have a stationary solution.
> Let c(t) be one of the solutions of this equation. Then,
> $\ \ \exists t_0$ s,t $\frac{d^{2}c}{dt^{2}}(t_0)=0 and  $\frac{dc}{dt}(t_0)=0 $
> >⇔$\forall t \in domain[c] ,\ \  c(t)=const$".

That is, even ordinary differential equations with stationary solutions may have stationary and non-stationary solutions. Since the solution of ordinary differential equations depends on initial conditions, there should theoretically exist "initial conditions that result in a stationary solution" and "initial conditions that result in an unsteady solution" in equations with both stationary and unsteady solutions. We want to characterize the distinction between the two by such things as initial conditions or stopping points.

In some biological textbooks, it is often said that 'the logistic equation has a stationary solution under the condition that the initial velocity is 0,'. But I don't really understand why that sufficients the condition above  to be a stationary solution. In fact, in the equation of motion, an initial velocity of 0 does not necessarily mean a stationary solution. for example,
$$\frac{d^2 y}{dt^3}(t) = -g$$
, it falls freely even with an initial velocity of 0.

Of course, it is a bit unusual to consider "initial velocity" as an initial condition in first-order ordinary differential equations. Normally, just the "initial position" is sufficient. However, if you take the initial position wisely, the "initial velocity" will be determined. For example, in the above equation, the initial velocity is 0 when x(0)=2 and when x(0)=0.　Actually,

If x(0)=2, then
$$\frac{dx}{dt}(0) = 4(1-0.5x(0))x(0)= 4(1-0.5\times 2)\times 2 =0$$
If x(0)=0, then
$$\frac{dx}{dt}(0) = 4(1-0.5x(0))x(0)= 4(1-0.5\times 0)\times 0 =0$$

And for this equation,
$$\frac{d^2 x}{dt^2} = \frac{d}{dt} (4(1-0.5x)x)
=4(1-0.5x) \frac{dx}{dt}  +4 \frac{d}{dt}  (1-0.5x)$$
$$=4(1-x/2)  \frac{dx}{dt}  -4\frac{x}{2}  dx/dt = 4(1-x)  dx/dt$$

then,
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=0 \Longrightarrow　\frac{d^2 x}{dt^2} = 4(1-x)\frac{dx}{dt} = 4(1-x)\times 0＝0$$

That means, as far as the logistic equation is concerned,
if we determine the initial position (initial concentration,x(0)) so that the initial velocity (dx/dt(0)) is 0, the 'initial condition' for acceleration is also 0. However, in general ordinary differential equations, it is unclear for me whether ``if we determine the initial position (initial concentration) such that the initial velocity is 0, the 'initial condition' for acceleration becomes 0.''

Just as it is mathematically strange to consider initial velocity in a first-order differential equation, it may be strange to consider an "initial condition" for acceleration in a second-order differential equation, but it is often found in physics textbooks. It is written that If the 'initial condition' of acceleration and the initial velocity are both 0, it becomes a stationary solution.

Well, there may be cases where you can figure it out by actually solving it, but if there is a way to determine it a priori without solving it, please let me know. (It is probably determined by a first-order differential equation or a second-order differential equation.)

In other words, the gist of the question is, "For an equation that has a steady solution, what initial conditions should be used to obtain a steady solution?" If the equation does not have a steady solution in the first place, it is impossible to create "initial conditions that have a steady solution," so we assume that the equation itself has a steady solution.

Comment: I'm confused by your notation $dx/dt(0)$. Do you mean that $X(0)=0$, where $X(x)$ is the right-hand side of the ODE $dx/dt = X(x)$?

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking: the derivative has to be $0$ *everywhere*, not just at $0$, in order for the function to be constant.  I.e., using your symbols (if I am reading them correctly, and I am not at all sure), you'd need $dx/dt=0$ rather than $dx/dt(0)=0$.

Comment: @JulioDiEgidio: I suspect that the zero in $dx/dt(0)$ is referring to $x=0$ rather than $t=0$. (See my comment above.)

Comment: @HansLundmark  I can't parse your comment either, but that's me. :)  Anyway, maybe wrongly, I was rather reading it as ${\frac {d x(t)} {dt}}(0)$, namely the derivative of $x(t)$ w.r.t. $t$ calculated at zero.  [I should have refrained from commenting, but your comment wasn't there yet when I wrote mine: I do not really understand the question itself, and I was curious...]

Comment: @JulioDiEgidio: Yes, that interpretation is the only one that makes sense in my opinion too. But I've seen many students come up with the somewhat misguided idea that since the right-hand side of the ODE $dx/dt = X(x)$ is a function of $x$, it's OK to write the left-hand side as a function of $x$ too: “$\frac{dx}{dt}(x)$”. (And then they continue by writing $d \dot x / dx$ when they mean $X'(x)$...) And I suspect that this is what has happened here.

Comment: For the dx/dt = 4(1-0.5x)x  if dx/dt(0)=0, then x(t)=Const an I rigt?　However, in the equation of motion, dx/dt=0 does not mean a steady solution. Is this also correct?

Comment: @BlueVarious please format your question and equations with MathJax

Comment: What is the Math Jax？

Comment: [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: If you want an answer, you will need to clarify what you mean by $dx/dt(0)$ (see comments above). What you're writing doesn't make much sense in its current form.

Comment: dx/dt(0) means the Initial velocity.

Comment: OK, so it was *not* as I thought then!

Comment: In the case of a first-order differential equation, it is sufficient to give x(0) as the initial condition, and there is no need to give (dx/dt)(0) as the initial condition, which may have caused confusion. However, (dx/dt)(0) is ``substituting 0 into the curve created by time differentiating x(t)'', and in differential equation problems, ``(dx/dt)(0)= I thought that writing "0" meant that the initial velocity was 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prescribing the initial velocity is a very strange kind of initial condition for a first-order ODE $\dot x = X(x)$ (which might explain all the confusion in the comments, where we were finding it hard to believe that you *really* meant $\dot x$ at time zero when you wrote $dx/dt(0)$).

Typically you would prescribe what $x(0)$ is. However, requiring that $\dot x(0)=0$ is the same thing as prescribing that $x(0)=x_0$, where $x_0$ is some zero of $X(x)$ (which is of course only possible if there *are* any such zeros). And that would mean that $x_0$ is an equilibrium point so that $x(t)=x_0$ for all $t$, provided that $X$ is nice enough so that you have uniqueness of solutions. (For example, a sufficient condition is that the function $X$ belongs to the class $C^1$. But there are counterexamples if $X$ is “bad”; for example $\dot x = 2 \sqrt{x}$ with $x(0)=0$ has infinitely many solutions, such as $x(t)=0$ for $t \le 0$ and $x(t)=t^2$ for $t>0$.)

Second-order ODEs can be written as systems of first-order ODEs, so similar remarks apply for them.

Comment: Thank you for answering. You got the gist of my question in a very short time, but it was certainly a question that was difficult to get across, so I explained my question carefully.
 I think there is a tendency for there to be more negative opinions about math problems related to chemistry and biology, in addition to math problems related to physics. There are probably many people who are not very familiar with the unique ways of thinking in chemistry and biology.

Comment: I would like answers to the following problem from the differential equation aspect. I got the following answer on my own. I think it is probably correct, but if it is wrong, I would appreciate comments.
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4865599/i-want-to-know-the-behavior-of-the-solution-without-solving-the-ordinary-differe/4867403#4867403