# I want to know the behavior of the solution without solving the ordinary differential equation for enzyme-substrate reactions.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, chemistry

I want to know the behavior of the solution without solving the ordinary differential equation for the following enzyme-substrate reactions.
[image]

This chemical reaction represents the process by which substrate S is
transformed into product P by the action of enzyme E.
In detail, the reaction takes place as follows;

- First, the enzyme E and S become the enzyme-substrate complex ES
- Next, the enzyme-substrate complex ES splits into the enzyme E and the product P.　We also assume that the initial concentration of E is >0.

Here, $k_1,k_2,k_3>0$, and [S] is the concentration of S, and the others similarly represent the concentrations of substances sandwiched between brackets. ES represents a complex of E and S.

**My question**

> Perhaps from the first equation, we expect to be able to say "that the concentration of substrate S  become zero after a sufficient time interval , but **can we prove this without solving the differential equation?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll use $T$ instead of $[ES]$ and drop all brackets. I'll also rescale $t$ so that $k_1=1$. The steady state equations read

$$\tag{1}
0=-SE+k_2T \\
0=-SE +k_2 T +k_3T \\
0=SE-k_2T-k_3T\\
0=T
$$

from which we learn that the product $SE\to 0$ as $t\to \infty$. For all $t$, a conserved quantity is

$$\tag{2}
E(t)+T(t)=H
$$

With an initial condition $E(0)\gt0$ it follows $H>0$ as all concentrations are non-negative. Evaluating (2) for large time demonstrates that

$$
E\to H >0 \qquad , \qquad t\to\infty
$$

So the only way to satisfy the product $SE\to0$ is $S\to0$ as $t\to\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is also a chemical reaction problem, this is a problem of qualitative consideration of solutions to differential equations, and is more of a mathematical problem than a chemistry problem. At one point, I obtained the following answers on my own. I think it is probably correct, but if it is wrong, I would appreciate comments.

From the equation ③ and ④, the material balance for substrate E can be obtained;
adding ③ and ④, $d([E]+[ES])/dt = 0 $ regardless of time,
and therefore, $-{k}_{1}[E]+{k}_{2}[ES] = constant$ is guaranteed on this system of differential equations alone, without making any a priori assumptions.

Taking into account the common knowledge of chemistry that at the t=∞,
all velocities become zero (in other words, chemical equilibrium is reached),we get

- In equation ①, $d[S]/dt =0$ at t=∞, so $-{k}_{1}[S][E]+ {k}_{2}[ES]=0$ at t=∞.
- In equation ④, $d[P]/dt =0$ t=∞, so [ES]=0 at t=∞.
- Therefore, from equations ① and ④, we get that $[S][E]=0$ at t=∞.
- Furthermore, from equation ④, the behavior at time ∞, [ES]=0, and the material balance [E]+[ES]=constant, and initial consentration of E>0 we know that [E]>0 at t=∞.
  -Hence, in conjunction with the fact that [S][E]=0 at t=∞, we have [S]=0.

Comment: I don't follow your last point, you know that $[E]+[ES]$ is constant and for $t\to\infty$, $[ES]\to0$, which means that $[E]\to\text{const.}$ why should this constant be zero? To find the steady state behaviour, setting the LHS of all your equations to zero yields either $[S]\to0$ or $[E]\to0$

Comment: @Sal Oops!! I had typo error!!  -k1[S][E]+ k2[ES]=0 not  [S][E]+[ES]=0